# Pressing "Home" in eclipse goes past white space, how to stop?

Tags: eclipse, editor, content-assist

When I press the home button in eclipse it goes all the way to the beginning of the line, even through white space.

Is there a way I can make it stop on the last non-whitespace character instead?

**What's happening now:** (the vertical line represents the cursor position)

```
      var foo = | bar
```

pressing home...

```
|      var foo =  bar
```

What I want to happen instead

```
      |var foo =  bar
```

Comment: Java editor does this automatically. Pressing home key takes you to the first non whitespace char, again pressing home key will take you to the start of line.

Comment: I guess my configuration got messed up, do you know where I could change it back to the default?

Comment: delete **.metadata** folder in your workspace and restart eclipse. Note: deleting this folder causes all preferences to reset to their default values. Verify all preference after restart.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without deleting the metadata folder?